# Is it safe to visit Nepal during the outbreak of COVID-19?

Tags: nepal, covid-19

As Nepal is neighbouring country of China as well Nepal is celebrating **visit Nepal 2020** this year.

Updates about COVID-19 in Nepal. This is useful for all travellers who are planning to travel in spring 2020.

Comment: Any international travel is affected by the virus this spring, we do not need a question per country.

Comment: @Willeke its Important to ask about Nepal, because its neighboring country of China and Nepal is celebrating visit Nepal 2020. So many travelers are asking this question in various forums. Many trekking and expedition to Everest groups were booked their packages 1 to 2 years before, so this information is for them.

Comment: Travel in Nepal is one thing, travel to Nepal is an other and for more and more countries people should not travel international. And many countries have special events, which may have to be cancelled.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/154396/18374

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to travel any country in Spring 2020 please read more about Corona virus .

- [WHO Advisory](https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/advice-for-public)
- [Q&A on corona viruses](https://www.who.int/news-room/q-a-detail/q-a-coronaviruses)
- [Current Country-wise Updates](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries)
- [Guardian Live](https://www.theguardian.com/world/live/2020/mar/03/coronavirus-live-updates-china-latest-news-us-australia-deaths-markets-italy-iran-update-cases-italy-south-korea-japan)
- [Live view on Map](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6)

Now lets talk about Nepal. Currently there is not any positive case mentioned in Nepalese citizens. Nepal is not providing on arrival visas from March 5 to march 31 2020 (can be extended)  for China, South Korea, Italy, Iran, Hong Kong.
Athough Nepal is safe currently, If you are planning to travel Nepal in spring 2020 please extend to Autumn

Comment: I can’t open a couple of the links in your answer. What is the official source for saying ‘if you’re planning to travel to Nepal in spring 2020 please extend to autumn’?

Comment: I admire your post but this is totally waste of time to put such things over here.